# Jquery load url underground

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<div class="wrap-box-video" id="31">
     <div class="addfav">
     </div>
     <img src="/etc.jpg" />
</div>
```

and with this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.addfav").click(function(e){
       window.location = "?wpfpaction=add&postid=" + $(this).parents(".wrap-box-video").attr("id");
   });
});
```

i want to load the `?wpfpaction=add&postid=31` (in this exemple) but not to show in the url tab i want this to be underground. if i'm on `exemple.com` page and i click the `addfav` div i want the exemple.com to be the same but the script to work.

Comment: if you want load the data with this url then you can use ajax call..thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about changing what text appears in the browser tab, you can alter the [title](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp) element of the HTML rendered at you ?wpfaction endpoint.

If you want to change what the actual URL that appears in the URL bar, see [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: The `?wpfaction` code adds the respective video to a favorite list. But i want to load this action when the button/div is clicked but not to show in the url or reload/change the page. The respective url to remain the same.

Comment: Oh use $.ajax({url: '?wpfaction...'}) instead of window.location = '..'